# using OR in sqlite3 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I want to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
Something.where(:user => "hello" or :user => "bye")
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing an OR on the same field, you should be able to pass in an array:

```
Something.where(:user => ["hello", "bye"])
```

Otherwise, you would need to build an OR SQL query:

```
Something.where("user = ? or user = ?", "hello", "bye")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Something.where("user = ? OR user = ?", 'hello', 'bye')
```

or even this:

```
Something.where("user IN (?)", ['hello', 'bye'] )`
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the existing answers, [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) at work:

```
Something.where(Something.arel_table[:attr].in(["val1", "val2"]))
```

Using a simple wrapper over Arel (https://gist.github.com/1333253):

```
Something.where(Something[:attr] >> ["val1", "val2"])
```